# parse.intialize(this,"xyz","xyz") has errors

Tags: android

The `parse.intialized` is underlined as soon as I enter my application and client keys. The program crashes when I create a local method of `parse.initialize`. The logcat report for the crash is a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

```
public class Parse extends Application{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();


        Parse.initialize(this, "rJYOXb5wXJ7tSM0FVleyueBnDFeJpUQ3vOl0oDq9", "a0CEcqJC7fGKKWPlAt8X79ojPfdKfW8Mq42vaC5b");

    }

}
```

Comment: Copy and paste the error, please.

Answer (score 1):

Explain in detail .Do u made parseObject ?Or parseUser Object ?

For eclipse-
Do u added parse-*.jar i  your lib ? Add lib and Also add bolts something jar if needed .

Also the error may be bcoz in one project you have to initialize it just once and that too before creating any object or using parse !

Thanks